# How to embed a Highcharts chart to jekyll blog post?

Tags: javascript, highcharts, jekyll

I want to display this simple highcharts example (http://www.highcharts.com/docs/getting-started/your-first-chart) on my jekyll blog hosted on github , but could not get it rendered, any help is appreciated.

I used the twitter boostrap template, should not be the problem, my D3.js charts works well.

This is my blog post page, which is not rendering.

```
---
layout: post
category : js
tagline: "Testing highcharts"
tags : [highcharts]
---
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js">
</script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js">
</script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto">
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(function () {
        $('#container').highcharts({
            title: {
                text: 'Monthly Average Temperature',
                x: -20 //center
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com',
                x: -20
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
                    'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Temperature (°C)'
                },
                plotLines: [{
                    value: 0,
                    width: 1,
                    color: '#808080'
                }]
            },
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: '°C'
            },
            legend: {
                layout: 'vertical',
                align: 'right',
                verticalAlign: 'middle',
                borderWidth: 0
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Tokyo',
                data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
            }, {
                name: 'New York',
                data: [-0.2, 0.8, 5.7, 11.3, 17.0, 22.0, 24.8, 24.1, 20.1, 14.1, 8.6, 2.5]
            }, {
                name: 'Berlin',
                data: [-0.9, 0.6, 3.5, 8.4, 13.5, 17.0, 18.6, 17.9, 14.3, 9.0, 3.9, 1.0]
            }, {
                name: 'London',
                data: [3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8]
            }]
        });
    });

</script>
```

Comment: are you getting any JS errors in console ?

Comment: Have you live demo of your website, cause defaulty it works without any problems.

Comment: sure, this is the one I would like to see http://jsfiddle.net/rQAsp/,this is failed Highcharts post http://tongzzz.github.io/js/2014/06/29/Highcharts.js/ and this is the sucessful D3.js one http://tongzzz.github.io/lessons/2014/03/26/d3.js/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The console error for you Highcharts example `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` means that the Highcharts library is not loaded before `$('#container').highcharts({...});` starts.

Try removing the line of code `$(function () {` and the last javascript line `});`

Comment: Fantastic! Glad to hear